# Getting error :name 'webdriver' is not defined for appium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I was recording a sample script through appium Inspector and while I was running, I am getting an error like this. My Script is in python language.

```
File "second.py", line 14, in <module>
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps) NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined
```

Below is my script.

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

success = True
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.2'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 6'
desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-podyodvceucybuaaiiuoprthidqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app')

wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
wd.implicitly_wait(60)

def is_alert_present(wd):
    try:
        wd.switch_to_alert().text
        return True
    except:
        return False

try:
    wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
    wd.find_element_by_name("Sign In").click()
finally:
    wd.quit()
    if not success:
        raise Exception("Test failed.")
```

Please help

Answer (score 9):

You need to *import `webdriver`*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Or, `import selenium.webdriver` --but then you'd need to prefix your call to webdriver with `selenium.`

Answer (score 1):

The line it is failing on is `wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`

At the top of your script you do `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver`.

Python is case-sensitive for variable names.  You either need to do:
`wd = WebDriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`
OR
`from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as webdriver`

I would recommend the former unless there's some reason you need it to be called webdriver.